# Magento 2 Checkout onepage how to create a custom step and save its value

Tags: magento2, checkout, database, orders, onepage-checkout

In **Magento 2.2.6** I am created the **custom checkout step** but its value is **not saved** in the **order** (database) I am take a reference into the following link:

> https://packagist.org/packages/sbodak/magento2-checkout-custom-form

Comment: Share your code or upload somewhere for help.

Comment: https://github.com/sbodak/magento2-checkout-custom-form